# Write a function that input a positive integer n and return the number of n-digit positive integers that divisible by 17

Tags: python, sage

I am working on Sage. Write a function that input a positive integer n and return the number of n-digit positive integers that divisible by 17. Be sure to account for the case where n=1. Test your program with inputs n=1,2,5.

What I understand that, for example, if I input n=1, it means that I need to check all the number from 0-9 which is divisible by 17. If I input n=2, it means that I need to check all the number between 0-99 inclusive which is divisible by 17.

I would not come up with a general formula which compute the length of n then take the right range of the number which is divisible by 17.

```
def positive(n):
for n in range(0, 10**n):
    if (n%17==0):
        print n,
```

The above code work with me, but it just print it the number which is divisible by 17. I was wondering how would I count them, so I would know how many numbers are divisible by 17.

Comment: Can't you just use `range(0, 10 ** n)` ?

Answer (score 4):

How about using number theory to simplify the problem, and use

```
def positive(n):
    return 10**n // 17 + 1
```

I believe Sage uses the caret rather than the double-asterisk for exponentiation, so you may instead use

```
10^n // 17 + 1
```

The plus-one includes the value 0, which is of course divisible by 17. You can check this with a longer version,

```
def positive(n):
    return len([x for x in range(10**n) if x % 17 == 0])
```

Comment: The square brackets are needed in both 2 and 3 for your last example - otherwise it'll be a generator expression which won't have a `len` and so thus fail... also - you need to `return` the value...

Comment: @JonClements: I corrected the `return` problem just before seeing your comment, but thanks for the clarification on the brackets. I don't use python 2.x.

Comment: You could re-write it as `sum(1 for v in range(10 ** n) if v % 17 == 0)` which'll avoid generating a list

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks again! I was wondering how to get the size of a generator without converting it to a list. Your answer does that pretty neatly. I'll leave my answer as is and upvote your comment, so people can better see who gets the credit for that idea.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def Multiples_17 (n):
    print("the list of numbers are: ",10^(n)//17-10^(n-1)//17)
    if n== 1:
        print (0)
    else:
        for i in range (10^(n-1)//17,10^(n)//17):
            k = 17 +(i*17)
            print(k)
```